# VBScript readline from file and check equal to

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a VBScript login/signup program I already have the signup part done but then while logging in it has to read a line from a file with ReadLine() but the file must see if the line read and the text typed are equal variables and I don't know how to do this

Comment: You will get better answers if you post what code you have already written and what problems you have had with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try reading the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more information on how to effectively use the site and get the most out of your time here.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, the = operator

```
If sInput = sRead Then
   ...
Else
   ...
End If
```

works well; if you have to care for case(in)sensitivity, use StrComp().

The comparison is not affected by the way you obtained the strings. If your file justs contains the string that has to be matched,

```
sRead = tsIn.ReadLine()
```

before the comparisons will 'work'; if your file contains more than that, you'll have to publish (relevant parts of) its content and how the relevant data can be identified.